# icalander 2.0 making an event every week from x to x

Tags: icalendar, rfc5545, rfc2445, webcal

I have an ICS file on iphone that i'm trying to have events with the following scenarios,

1 - event starts on day X at time X, event ends on same day x at time x (1 hour later)

```
DTSTART:20140910T214500Z
DTEND:   20140911T030000Z
```

2 - event starts on day X at time X
    recurs, every week on that day
            for 1 hour till day Y

```
DTSTART:20140910T214500Z
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20140925T000000Z
DTEND:20140911T030000Z
```

so in words, i want to make an event on the 5th that lasts for 1 hours. then i want to make an event wednesday the 10th that last for 1 hours, every week, till the end date i gave it.

Answer (score 0):

on both cases your `DTEND` is 1 day later: DTEND sept 11th whereas `DTSTART` is sept 10th.

You did not say what was wrong but this would be a good place to start.